# Перегрузка конструкторов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

В классе `A` есть 2 конструктора. Необходимо, чтобы при передаче в конструктор параметров типа `string` и `const char[]` использовался конструктор №2, а при передаче массива с другим типом данных - №1. Пишу такое:

```
template <typename R, size_t N> // №1
explicit A(const R (&X)[N],typename enable_if<!is_same<R,const char[]>::value>::type* = nullptr):... {}
explicit A(string const &str):... {} // №2
```

В итоге для инструкции `A<...> a("...")` вызывается конструктор №1.

Если же первый конструктор переписать так:

```
template <typename R, size_t N> // №1
explicit A(const R (&X)[N],typename enable_if<is_same<R,const char[]>::value>::type* = nullptr):... {} // убрал !
```

, то вызывается конструктор №2, хотя должно быть наоборот. Или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у Вас сравнение неверно, первый конструктор должен выглядеть так:

```
template <typename R, size_t N> // №1
explicit A(const R (&X)[N],typename enable_if<!is_same<R,char>::value>::type* = nullptr):... {}
```

Посмотрите, что у Вас такое `R` в шаблоне и поймёте почему.